# C Client socket data not able to read in Java Server

Tags: java, c, sockets, tcp

Java Server socket giving the wrong output when bytearray converted to string.
 C socket header format

```
int  tccode 4
int  len    4
char data[4088] 4088
```

C Struct format

```
Tc Code :1001   Size : 256  
#ifdef   __DTGPL1T__                                                                                                   
struct DTGPL1T_S                                                                                                    
{                                                                                                   
      // ENTRY ZONE 
      short       por1cur; 
      short       por2cur; 
      short       por1ten;
      short       por2ten;
      short       p1lvim1;
      short       p1lvim2;
      short       p1lvim3; 
      short       p2lvim1;
      short       p2lvim2;
      short       p2lvim3; 
      short       brc1 ;
      short       entrylt;                                                                                     short       enlopcar;                                                                                                    
      short       notchlen;                                                                                                 
      short       poruse;                                                                                                     
      short       p1remain;                                                                                                 
      short       p2remain;                                                                                                 
      short       eloopcap;                                                                                            
      short       elooplen;                                                                                               
      short       untielen;                                                                                                 
      short       entryspd;                                                                                         
      short       st8ten; 
      short       brc2  ; 
      short       scbtns; 
      short       scbel ; 
      short       scb1intr;
      short       scb2intr;
      short       scb3intr;
      short       st3ten; 
      short       brc3  ; 
      short       plettkts; 
      short       deli1ten; 
      short       d1loopcc;
      short       d1loopln; 
      short       d1loopcp;
      short       brc4  ; 
      short       br4ten;
      short       plcspd; 
      short       triwidt; 
      short       sthosingwidth  ; 
      short       trigap1;
      short       trigap2; 
      short       trigap3;
      short       trigap4;
      short       trilap1; 
      short       trilap2; 
      short       trilap3; 
      short       trilap4;
      short       aactwid; 
      short       adevwid;
      short       chopw ; 
      short       chopd ; 
      short       tristat;
      short       trispd; 
      short       trmtoplen; 
      short       deli2ten; 
      short       d2loopcc; 
      short       d2loopcp;
      short       d2loopln;                                                                                                   
      short       br5ten; 
      short       brc5  ; 
      short       wpd1sta;
      short       wpd2sta; 
      short       wpd3sta;
      short       wpd3asta;
      short       wpd4sta;
      short       wpd5sta;
      short       chvsen[2]; 
      short       wbsen[2]; 
      short       etcsen;
      short       wpdpass[6];
      short       wpdlen[6];
      short       pl_cv_next_move;                                                                                                   
      short       ccv1_lock_curr ;   
      short       ccv2_lock_curr ;  
      short       ewb1_lock_curr ; 
      short       ewb2_lock_curr ;
      short       etc_lock_curr  ; 
      short       eskd1_lock_curr;
      short       eskd2_lock_curr; 
      short       ecc1_lock_curr ; 
      short       ecc2_lock_curr ;
      short       st_wid_low_err ;

      short       st_wid_upp_err ; 


      short       trim_width_set;                                                                                           
      short       hadling_time;                                                                                                   

      short       spare01[14]    ;

      short       spare02[16]    ;

      //38 + 16 = 53 

};                                                                                                  
typedef struct DTGPL1T_S       DTGPL1T_T;                                                                                                   
typedef        DTGPL1T_T       *DTGPL1T_P;                                                                                                  
#define        DTGPL1T_LN      sizeof(DTGPL1T_T)                                                                                                    
#endif      // Eof of __DTGPL1T__
```

And Java server code

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
     //DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
     int tcCode = in.readInt();
     int length = in.readInt();
     if(tcCode == 1001) {

            byte[] messageByte = new byte[length];
            boolean end = false;
            StringBuilder dataString = new StringBuilder(length);
            int totalBytesRead = 0;
            while(!end) {

                int currentBytesRead = in.read(messageByte);
                totalBytesRead = currentBytesRead + totalBytesRead;
                if(totalBytesRead <= length) {                      
                    dataString
                      .append(new String(messageByte, 0, length - totalBytesRead + currentBytesRead));

                } else {
                    dataString
                      .append(new String(messageByte, 0, length - totalBytesRead + currentBytesRead));
                }
                if(dataString.length()>=length) {
                    end = true;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Message1  "+dataString);
            }
```

*MessageBytes getting like* [-1, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 35, 0, 33, 0, 30, 0, 45, 0, 40, 0, 35, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 10, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 5, -123, 0, 111, 3, 34, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, -25, 0, 24, -1, -2, -1, -3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 43, 37, -1, -35, 0, 0, 0, 72, 10, 42, 0, 0, 43, 37, 0, 0, 49, 126, 112, -30, 0, 5, 0, 5, 0, 11, 0, 12, -3, 68, -3, 68, -6, -20, -6, -20, 27, 86, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -13, -1, -7, 0, 0, 16, 107, 0, -99, 0, 80, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, -20, 4, -73, -1, 74, -1]
[Output screenshot][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRmej.png)

Comment: please include the tccode and len , and message in text that you put  in the hearder from C side . My shot in the dark : byte ordering inconsistent,  one is little-endian and the other big-endian

Comment: How is this C, C++ and Java?

Comment: @bigdataolddriverPlease check edited question I have added C Struct format, there is 3 Structs tc_code 1001 Size 256, tc_code 1002 Size 512, tc_code 1003 Size 280*3

Comment: Java is not C.  In Java, you should never, ever use Strings to hold bytes.  Use a byte array for that.  Creating a String out of a byte array is likely to corrupt some of the values, because they won’t all represent valid characters.

Comment: @VGR it's already storing byte array if you check my code you will get, but how to parse data from that byte array

Comment: 1. `String` is not a container for binary data. 2. You should be using `DataInputStream.readShort()` here, but beware endian issues. 3. Don't use structs as network protocols. There are a dozen ways they can go wrong, or change between releases. You need to write yourself a proper language-independent protocol definition, and implement a C and a Java library to send and receive it.

Comment: @NayanKagade Your byte array is being stored into `StringBuilder dataString`, and that is exactly what @VGR is correctly warning you against doing.

Comment: OT:  in general, it is a very poor practice to typedef a pointer.

Comment: Please post code that cleanly compiles, especially post the C code that transmits the data

Answer (score 2):

Unlike in C, a Java String is not suitable for holding bytes.  Converting bytes to a String [decodes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) the bytes, which means some values may be altered or lost.

Even if no values were altered, your data is not going to represent characters, so printing it as text will display nonsense.  For instance, many of your bytes are zero, which does not show at all in output, since character `\u0000` is a non-printing control character.

You should avoid Strings and StringBuilders entirely.  Instead, store your bytes in the byte array only:

```
while (totalBytesRead < length) {
    int currentBytesRead = in.read(messageByte,
        totalBytesRead, length - totalBytesRead);
    totalBytesRead = currentBytesRead + totalBytesRead;
}
```

Your data appears to consist entirely of `short` values, so, assuming the C client is built to regard `short` as a 16-bit value, and assuming the C compiler didn’t pad your `struct` members in order to word-align them, you can convert your bytes to a sequence of shorts using [ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) and [ShortBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ShortBuffer.html):

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(messageByte);
ShortBuffer shortBuffer = buffer.asShortBuffer();
```

To print them, retrieve them as an array and use [Arrays.toString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28short[]%29):

```
short[] values = new short[length / 2];
shortBuffer.get(values);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
```

Comment: I used your above code printing values [-1, 0, 0, 0, 35, 33, 30, 45, 40, 35, 0, 0, -1, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1413, 111, 802, 0, 0, 0, 717, 24, -2, -3, 0, 0, 0, 10445, -35, 0, 72, 2602, 0, 10445, 0, 12670, 28898, 5, 5, 11, 12, -700, -700, -1300, -1300, 6998, 0, 16, 16, 0, 0, 243, -7, 0, 4203, 157, 80, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -20, 1207, -182, -21, 470, -237, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 12670, 13106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1002, 0, 4096] in this format

Comment: Is that the data you were expecting?

Comment: no it's wrong, byte should be able to convert into char or string

Comment: I’m not sure what that means.  What are some example values for `por1cur`?  Are you saying it contains a character value?

Comment: your solution works for all short values but if struct contains some int & character values how that will work. Thanks

Comment: In that case, the first loop is the same: you still want to read the entire array into `messageByte`.  You will then need a combination of `asShortBuffer()` and similar methods like `asIntBuffer()`.  Exactly where and when you should invoke those methods will require careful analysis of your C structure;  compilers are free to word-align `struct` members, so even if you determine the exact byte offsets of various members, they might change in a future compilation.  Various compiler flags can also change the offsets.

Comment: Can you recommend which will be the good solution, so that I can implement that one

Comment: I recommend that you avoid sending a binary `struct`, as the exact byte offsets are not reliable, especially if you plan to compile on different architectures.  Use a format intended for communication between languages, like XML or JSON.

Comment: Please can you share any JSON example link that will work as per my data format if you know.

Comment: I am not familiar with any JSON tutorials in particular, but they’re easy to find by searching.

Comment: Because of some reason C client only struct format going to use not JSON. As per your above example for getting int value ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(messageByte); after  this line same like ShortBuffer I added intBuffer but values getting wrong.